# Is res.send(200) the same as res.status(200).send('OK') and the same as res.sendStatus(200);

Tags: node.js, express, httpresponse

Is `res.send(200)` the same as `res.status(200).send('OK')` and the same as `res.sendStatus(200)`?

I am using express.js and I am trying to intergrate webhooks where the docs say that you should send `res.send(200)` to show that you have received the web hook successfully. But, express tells me `res.send()` is deprecated. What should I use instead of `res.send(200)`

Should I use `res.status(200)` or `res.status(200).send('OK')` or `res.sendStatus(200)` or all are okay? Or something else

Comment: Did you try any of them? What happened? You could also look in the changelog: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/History.md#470--2014-07-25

Comment: In normally we are using `res.status(200).send("ResponseData")`